# Preferred deals information returned by Ad Exchange Seller API supposedly wrong

Tags: google-api

It seems that the data returned by the Ad Exchange Seller REST API about the "Preferred deals" of my account do not match what is shown under "Deals" in my web interface.

It even appears that, in my case, the returned deals are expired (cf. the endTime field).

Consequently, I would have two questions about this :

- Do "Preferred deals" in the API correspond to "Deals" in the web interface ?
- Is it possible (and how) to get the information concerning those said "Deals" with the API ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

- example (to Barett) : Thanks for the message. The API gives me 2 results, the most recent one being expired since January 2014 (I won't give names for now, sorry) while in my web interface, it seems I can't find those 2 results. The web interface even shows 45 open offers, and I would like to be able to access this data with the API.

Comment: an example might help?